# Powershell ISE - Choose script file when open a new window

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I'm trying to open a new Powershell ISE window providing my own script .ps1 file.

How can I accomplish that? Seems that the only way to open a new Powershell ISE window is with a blank script file, and not one one's may choose(i.e. `start powershell_ise.exe -file "myfile.ps1"` - That's not working).

Comment: You don't say how you are trying to open a new window.  Do you mean interactively?  Do you mean programmatically,  under a script that you would like to write?  If it's interactively, what's wrong with clicking "Open" and then selecting your script?  If its programmatically, is the calling script running under ISE or is it running under the Powershell console?

Comment: I assume you know about $Profile and its variants for running under ISE.  If not see help about_Profiles and help about_Powershell_ISE.exe.  These are available under powershell.  Can you tell us why $Profile doesn't address your problem?  This might help people who want to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a few solutions:

1) Use ISE twice, the only downside is that you'll see extra untitled doc

```
ise; ise ".\test.ps1"
```

2) You can start it in admin mode (from non-admin mode), it will force to create a new ISE:

```
Start-Process powershell_ise -ArgumentList ".\test.ps1" -Verb RunAs
```

3) Run as different user

```
Start-Process powershell_ise -ArgumentList "-noprofile .\test.ps1" -Credential $cred
```

Method 2/3 only open new ISE once though (until you close it)

Answer (score 0):

From inside powershell I run:

```
ise myfile.ps1
```

and it will open it.

Comment: When run inside the ISE it will simply open a new tab, not a new ISE window. That's what they already said in the question, by the way.

Comment: I'm not talking about running it in ISE. I said from PowerShell.

Comment: Yes, but *they* are talking about running it in ISE. Your answer completely sidesteps the problem they are having.

Comment: Yes I see what you are saying. I guess it seems very odd to me that you'd purposely use a GUI editor to try and open another GUI using the command line inside of the GUI rather than just using a new tab inside current session.  So is this even a programming question then? Doesn't looks like it to me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, I don't think it's possible. I've done a quick Google and found the answer that campbell.rw posted but the same thing occurred. Similarly, I've just tried to start a new PowerShell ISE process using the following command...

```
Start-Process -FilePath C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe -ArgumentList "-File .\testscript.ps1"
```

...but like you mentioned in the comments below the existing answer, instead of opening a new instance of PowerShell ISE it simply creates a new tab in the same instance with the script I specified in the 'ArgumentList' parameter.

Comment: Well, that's hardly surprising as the exact same thing happens here. It doesn't matter *how* the process is started. It's the new ISE instance that chooses to tell the first one to open the file in a new tab, so things like whether using the `ise` alias, or `Start-Process` are completely irrelevant to the outcome.

Comment: Agreed, I think powershell_ise.exe is just being too smart for it's own good and recognises that you would essentially be creating a new process of itself for no reason, hence it opens it in a new tab lol

Comment: It also doesn't seem to be possible to open a new window programmatically and manipulating it afterwards by code. Within the current window you have access to `$psISE` from which you can open files in new tabs, though.

Comment: I thought of doing that too but alas, it seems to be the same situation